# Import Sent Items from Outlook to MS-Access via Get External Data

Tags: ms-access, outlook, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

Using the post at http://www.everydayanalytics.ca/2013/12/whats-in-my-inbox-data-analysis-of.html

I thought I could Import Outlook data in Access, I have access to both 2010 and 365 versions, but none can import Sent Items.

Following the wizard:
Step 1:
[image]

Step 2:
[image]

I get the following error
[image]

This only happens when choosing a folder that is not located under Inbox.

Can anyone offer a suggestion on how to get the data from Sent Items, including timestamps.

I can export the data from Outlook, but the export does not contain timeline information.